# selenium how to scroll down page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scroll down a web-page using selenium webdriver 2.37 using the code below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php
require_once('lib/__init__.php');
    $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
    $capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities,1000);
    $driver->get('https://twitter.com/hashtag/DF14?src=hash');          
    $driver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::ARROW_DOWN);
    sleep(rand(5,7));
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for scrolling down? Because the page is entirely accessible even if not visible.

Comment: Sir I want to scrap twiiter.com/handler of all entire page so scrolling is must i guess without scrolling is it possible?

Comment: use **PAGE_DOWN** key instead of **ARROW_DOWN** or inject java script explicitly: `JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");`